# No response from addPart operation when trying to upload parts of .tpk to AGOL (Python, requests, ArcGIS REST API)

Tags: arcgis-online, python-2.7, arcgis-rest-api, request

Trying to automate the updating of a large .tpk on AGOL. When the .tpk is updated on my servers I do the following:

- Break into parts
- Call updateItem operation with multipart = true
- Make a request to upload each part using addPart
- Make a request with the commit function to finalize the update to the .tpk on AGOL

My issue is that I get no response when trying to use addPart, then when the commit operation is hit in my code it says there are no parts to commit. A very odd result as something is definitely happening when the addParts operation is performed. Memory usage kicks up to ~ 3GB (1gb files so this seems right) and each addPart takes maybe 5 minutes or so complete and move to the next. It's not a firewall/proxy issue with the request as I've made multiple request in this environment to AGOL and had no issues getting responses.

Code:

```py
update_url = 'https://lipa.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/{}/items/{}/update'.format(username,tpk_id)

up_data = {'f':'json',
    'token':token,
    'title': layer_name,
    'itemId':tpk_id,
    'type': 'Tile Package',
    'overwrite': 'true', # existing item, overwrite is set to true
    'async':'true',
    'multipart':"true"}


update_response = requests.post(update_url, up_data=data, verify = cert).json()

print update_response


part_num = 1
part_url = 'https://lipa.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/{}/items/{}/addPart'.format(username,tpk_id)

for part in os.listdir(parts):

    path = r"\\psegliny.com\oms\oms_gis_prd\fileshare_mapping\cache_extent\es_secondary_tpks\full_service_area"

    part = path + "\{}".format(part)

    print part
    print(str(part_num))


    ##files_up = {"file": open(part, 'rb')}
    with open(part, "rb") as f:
        files_up = {"file":f}

        data = {'f':'json',
                'token':token,
                'partNum':part_num}


        part_response = requests.post(part_url,data = data,files=files_up,verify=cert)
    part_num+=1
    try:
        jres = json.loads(part_response.text)
        print jres
    except:
        print "no response"
    ##print add_part_response

commit_url = 'https://lipa.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/{}/items/{}/commit'.format(username,tpk_id)

data = {'f':'json',
'token':token}

commit_response = requests.post(commit_url,data=data,verify=cert).json()

print commit_response
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? It's very odd that I get no response at all, at the very least I should get a failed/success response back (as per the documentation)

Comment: I can't answer your question - but if you want to use a ready made tool, or to copy/paste code, you can grab SharePackage2 from here: https://github.com/arcpy/sample-gp-tools/tree/master/SharePackage2 which does multipart upload doing addPart and commit.

Comment: You're the one who wrote this tool? I see that you achieved multi part uploads through other means not using the rest api operations..I'd love to reverse engineer that for myself could you point me in the right direction for understanding it? For now I'll probably use your tool, as it does exactly what share package could not...work from the command line/outside of arc w/o being prompt to sign into AGOL(or atleast I gather that from your description).

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it a few years ago. It does use the REST API. The biggest difference between your code and that is `requests`. At the time requests wasn't included, so I had to write all the multipart upload code using built-in modules. If you can use requests, I'd suggest doing so, It handles so much. Regardless of requests or built-ins the code will show the pattern you need if you want to do multipart upload (addItem > addPart > commit)

Comment: After re-reading, I see you're doing an UPDATE. I dont recall exactly the behavior of the tool if doing update (overwrite). You'll need to test that scenario. Hopefully I took that workflow into account with SP2?

Comment: According to the docs it is used in the same manner as addItem; you call the operation first with multipart enabled, add parts, commit. I'll get back to you on if SP2 works for my use-case and if not offer advice on changes.  I'm looking through your code now, but if you could at what line do you make the addPart calls? You're on another level then me in terms of skill, I don't use classes often like this so it's a little hard for me to figure out all the moving parts

Comment: @KHibma found it and I see some differences between us that I think are probably responsible for why my code is not working. Your code is awesome btw, definitely a good reference for me

Comment: The `encode_multipart_data` was the hardest part of all that. I got a lot of help on stackexchange while getting that working.

Comment: @KHibma SharePackage2 runs fine from my IDE but when I try to run from command line I get a bogus traceback to line 53 of SharePackage2.py saying the error was 'description'...line 53 checks the file extension so I have no idea what this means. The way I pulled the tool into my script was my importing the tool box so maybe it was something with that? Going to try importing the function directly from the script I guess and hope that fixes it.

Comment: @KHibma so I managed to get things working by importing the function directly from SharePackag2.py which gave me a valid traceback to line 119 where I was getting a key error for both description and credits...super weird because if I run the same code with the same package I don't get that error

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this for future reference, this works for me. It assumes all the files are under 5Mb because if they aren't you will have to upload them as chunks. This uploads a service definition file to AGOL

```
update_url = '{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/update'.format(self.base_url, self.username, self.sd_item_id)

query_dict = {"file": file_name,
                "filename"
                "type": "Service Definition",
                "title": self.service_name,
                "f": "json",
                'multipart': 'true',
                'partNum': 1,
                "token": self.token}
details = {'filename': file_name}

r = requests.post(update_url, data=query_dict)
jsonResponse = json.loads(r.text)

if "success" in jsonResponse:
    item_id = jsonResponse['id']

    add_part_url = '{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/addPart'.format(self.base_url, self.username, item_id)
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fobj:
        files = {'file': fobj}
        r = requests.post(add_part_url, files=files,  data=query_dict)
    jsonResponse = json.loads(r.text)
    if not "success" in jsonResponse:
        raise Exception("Error adding part:: " + str(jsonResponse))

    # commit the file
    commit_url = '{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/commit'.format(self.base_url, self.username, item_id)
    parameters = {'token': self.token, 'f': 'json'}
    r = requests.get(commit_url, params=query_dict)
    jsonResponse = json.loads(r.text)

    if not "success" in jsonResponse:
        raise Exception("Error commiting file:: " + str(jsonResponse))

    # wait for valid status: partial | processing | failed | completed
    status = 'processing'
    while status == 'processing' or status == 'partial':
        status = self.item_status(item_id)['status']
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if status == 'failed':
                raise IOError("{} SD file not uploaded\n\tresponse:{}".format(file_name, str(status)))

    logging.info("Updated SD: {}".format(item_id))
    return True
else:
    raise IOError("{} SD file not uploaded\n\tresponse:{}".format(file_name, jsonResponse))

# Check the status of an item.
# Returns the item's status. (partial | processing | failed | completed)
def item_status(self, item_id, jobId=None):
    url = '{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/status'.format(self.base_url, self.username, item_id)
    parameters = {'token': self.token, 'f': 'json'}
    if jobId:
        parameters['jobId'] = jobId
    r = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    jsonResponse = json.loads(r.text)
    return jsonResponse
```